How to set up AWS SNS for message filtering?
I am trying to create a subscriber to SNS topic with a simple filter policy, after some debugging, I find that the simplest possible setting on the subscriber still not working though I did everything following the official document here. I finally do a very simple experiment and here is what I did:
I create an SNS topic and set up 2 SQS subscriber to subscribe it, one doesn't have filter, the other one have a simple filter policy of
{"SensorName":["test"]}
I then published the following message directly via SNS console by setting "SensorName" attribute to 'test', here is the received message content:
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "6d39fd3d-8792-55d9-b45d-a39230423be9",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:162092913718:test_filter",
  "Subject" : "11",
  "Message" : "1111111aa",
  "Timestamp" : "2024-05-04T04:12:00.004Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "PQ5EPMc+zVcTLecOzwnCCrss7dWDX+9yuccLhvfsnX56gaThpeuxyQfWkTDXuzfcIk5BQHqOmHq+3Fjrn1wJB17FI3gozVlYVd4PM0dgHoivmfcY6724/zufhtZDvbw1b8PE6x5rXEg3D3R6dCdUWdf0Fky5twR1Zwnegw3KMsPPSPWrqyLjj7BDvZOUaLpoq6oeUDmFPkOIt2hV9Kn1Tdgyn3i3ifJvpt09bEnrwFen61+vDuiuEGeCi7uqKG4ggML2QX12dtyEzU7onfJrYj+7Ha6FAS87TcZPm9Qwn1gqcgbuts2IILHyfQEkajX4ZUGAnAGUfWAUOO882GW9jw==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-60eadc530605d63b8e62a523676ef735.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:162092913718:test_filter:4739bfc7-ce1f-4426-be50-6e1573fe9e2c",
  "MessageAttributes" : {
    "SensorName" : {"Type":"String","Value":"test"}
  }
}

The SQS without filter receive it (and above is what's received), the one with the filter doesn't, which shouldn't be the case, and I can't find what's going wrong in such a simple example? There must something critical I've been missing. Can anyone help？

You need to active Enable raw message delivery on the SQS subscriptions in the Amazon SNS Topic.
It isn't obvious that you need to do this, and there isn't any documentation that specifically says you need to do so, but it was previously explored in 2017 here: How to add SQS message attributes in SNS subscription?
I just tested it again (in 2024) and can confirm that the subscription filters only worked correctly when Raw Message Delivery was enabled on the subscription.
Interestingly, the Applying a subscription filter policy - Amazon Simple Notification Service documentation does include instructions for activating Raw Message Delivery, but it doesn't actually say that it is required. But it seems that it is required.

I have submitted Feedback on the above documentation page to request AWS to make this requirement more explicit.

I got the same result even enable the raw message delivery, whenever I add a filter, I won't be able to get any message on the SQS end.
